# NSMenu - @selector(doSomething) not doing anything when I click on it

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

Thanks in advance for the help.

PROBLEM: '@selector(doSomething)' IS NOT CALLING THE ' - (void)doSomething:(id)sender' METHOD

I am trying to get the item in the status bar to call the doSomething method but when I click on it nothing seems to happen.

What am I doing wrong?

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    sync_control *controlObject = [[sync_control alloc] init];
    [controlObject startSyncApp];
}
```

SyncControl.m

```
    NSStatusBar *syncStatusBar;
    NSStatusItem *syncStatusItem;

- (void) startSyncApp
{
    syncStatusBar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    syncStatusItem = [syncStatusBar statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];

    NSImage *statusItemImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
    statusItemImage.template = YES;
    statusItemImage.size = NSMakeSize(18.0,18.0);

    [syncStatusItem setImage:statusItemImage];
    [syncStatusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

    [syncStatusItem setMenu:[self waitingState:Nil]]; 
}


- (NSMenu *)waitingState:(id)sender
{
    NSMenu *localMenu;

    //Create the NSMenu
    localMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sync"];
    [localMenu setAutoenablesItems:NO];
    [localMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Do something now..." action:@selector(doSomething:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:1];

    return localMenu;
}


- (void)doSomething:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"It works!");
}
```

Comment: Take a careful look at what you are trying to add to NSMenuItem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be that the menu item has an action selector, but no target. Try this:

```
NSMenuItem *someItem = [localMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Do something now..." action:@selector(doSomething:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
[someItem setTarget: self];
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: On StackOverflow you thank people by voting answers and comments up or down and/or marking an answer as "answers the question".